# Disable payment if Drupal Commerce Order Balance Total is <250

Tags: 7, rules, commerce

I am trying to disable a payment option if the order balance total is over $250. I currently have the following, but it throws an error as there is nothing to drill down into after "order-total:"

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi there. When taking screenshots, please try to make your window no more than 600px wide. Probably you think it's readable now, but you know what's there already so your brain fills in ;) I'll link a screenshot to it's full-res version, but please re-take it in a more fitting size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the correct condition is called: Price Comparison and not Balance total

see here: [image: http://prntscr.com/25vfzb]

Answer (score 1):

Value must be in Cents: for 50$ the value must be 5000
See here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1294606

Comment: That's kind of beyond the main point, but well worth reminding